# struts 2 assigning value of property tag to hidden field

Tags: struts2

I want to assign the value from field Description to a hidden field test.
But the problem is the "Description" contains sequence of words and the following code is assigning only first word to "test"

`<s:hidden value=<s:property  value="Description" />  name="test">`

I am kind of new to struts. Can someone please help.
Also it would be nice if i get to know good tutorial links of struts2.

Comment: is the description is of your action class property?

Comment: yes description is a property. See only first word is assigned becoz hidden tag value is considering white space as delimiter

Answer (score 10):

If this is a property in your action class you need not to use `<s:property value="Description" />` as the `Description` will be available at the top of value stack and you can use OGNL to fetch the value from value-stack.This is what you need to do

```
<s:hidden  value="%{description}" name="test" />
```

Please make sure the `value` in hidden filed should be similar to the name of property in your action class as it will be resolved to either the getter and setter in your action class or the public property defined in your action.

So this means `value="%{description}"` will be converted by OGNL like `getDescription()` and will try to find the getter in your action class to fetch the property value.

Comment: helped me 4 years later. @saket you never marked this as the answer.

Comment: How can i send this <s:property />

Answer (score 2):

```
<s:hidden  value="%{description}" name="test" />
```

Comment: How can i send this <s:property />